# LiteLLM and Llama-Index Service Context creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, large-language-model, llama-index

I am going crazy with finding a solution to this. I am working with a proxy server for OpenAI models. I'm using an ssh tunnel to hit the server on my localhost.

```
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(base_url="http://localhost:8000", api_key="sk-xxx")

response = client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt_35_turbo", messages = [
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "this is a test request, write a short poem"
    }
])

print(response)
```

This works perfectly. I need to use this with llamaindex, so I need to define my llm and embedding_model, and serve them to my service_context like so:

```
llm = OpenAI(model="text-davinci-003", temperature=0, max_tokens=256)
embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding()
text_splitter = SentenceSplitter(chunk_size=1024, chunk_overlap=20)
prompt_helper = PromptHelper(
    context_window=4096,
    num_output=256,
    chunk_overlap_ratio=0.1,
    chunk_size_limit=None,
)

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm,
    embed_model=embed_model,
    text_splitter=text_splitter,
    prompt_helper=prompt_helper,
)
```

where I would be calling my own "ada-02" model through the server as well. How can I make this work with my setup? I am totally unable to find any answer to this anywhere and I've already wasted days trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from llama_index.llms import OpenAILike

llm = OpenAILike(api_base="http://localhost:8000",\
                 model="name_you_gave_to_the_model",
                 api_key="sk-xxx")
```

@LLamaIndex folks, for godsake put this properly in the documentation, I ran into [this](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/api_reference/llms/openai_like.html) by accident after days wasted trying to write my own wrapper...